# How do I export a video from Blender?

Tags: export, video

I edited a video using Blender today and now I cannot export it. The video is fairly short I just need to make some cuts and add a couple of clips together. Do you guys know how I can export the video?

Comment: Make sure that the project properties panel has sequencer enabled and set up your render codec to include a video codec with audio. I'm sure that there is a comprehensive explanation here somewhere

Answer (score 3):

assuming you have the video all cut together in the video sequence editor pannel, open a properties panel and go the the render section (first button with a picture of a camera) there will be all your render setting whch you may personalize. For rendering 3D you would want to first export as PNG files and then post render bring the PNG sequence into the Video sequence editor render it into a final video file, but it sounds like you are trying to do a final video render in which case you go to the output section and choose FFMPEG video, Then under encoding > container you generally want to go with either Quicktime (.mov) or mpeg-4 (.mp4) and for the codec use H.264

Comment: Yeah, and how do I get the clip? Where is teh "Export" or "Render" button that puts me the mp4. file into my folder for later use?

Comment: @MartinMüsli you can hit `ctrl+F12` or use the app menu `Render > Render Animation`